# Python: How to group a list of objects by their characteristics or attributes?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to separate a list of objects into sublists, where objects with same attribute/characteristic stay in the same sublist.

Suppose we have a list of strings:

```
["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
```

We want to separate the strings based on their length as follows:

```
[['sentence'], ['a'], ['is', 'of'], ['This'], ['seven', 'words']]
```

The program I currently come up with is this

```
sentence = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
word_len_dict = {}
for word in sentence:
    if len(word) not in word_len_dict.keys():
        word_len_dict[len(word)] = [word]
    else:
        word_len_dict[len(word)].append(word)


print word_len_dict.values()
```

I want to know if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Better in what way? I personally see no problems with that implementation (assuming it works, I haven't checked that)

Comment: As your data is not sorted, you've found the canonical method. You could use `word_len_dict = defaultdict(list)` instead so you don't have to keep testing if the key is present already. If your data were to be sorted already, use `itertools.groupby()`.

Comment: Or use `dict.setdefault()`, which often makes using a `defaultdict` unnecessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Note your list must be sorted first (*more expensive than your method OP*).

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
>>> print [list(g[1]) for g in groupby(sorted(l, key=len), len)]
[['a'], ['is', 'of'], ['This'], ['seven', 'words'], ['sentence']]
```

or if you want a *dictionary* ->

```
>>> {k:list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=len), len)}
{8: ['sentence'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['is', 'of'], 4: ['This'], 5: ['seven', 'words']}
```

Comment: Sorting is a on O(NlogN) operation. Grouping by using a dictionary is O(N). Only use `groupby` if the data is *already sorted*. If not, then stick to the method the OP already devised, as it'll be faster (especially when the number of items to group grows).

Comment: Oh I completely agree. It's why I made a note of it. There's nothing wrong with OP's method, just thought I'd offer an alternative if speed isn't a concern/his data is already sorted.

Answer (score 7):

With `defaultdict(list)`, you can omit the key-existence check:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_len_dict = defaultdict(list)

for word in sentence:
    word_len_dict[len(word)].append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

The doc of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) has a example that matches exactly what you want.

```
keyfunc = lambda x: len(x)
data = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
groups = []
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    groups.append(list(g))
print groups
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the dict only by using `setdefault` function:

```
sentence = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
word_len_dict = {}
for word in sentence:
    word_len_dict.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
```

What `setdefault` does is set the key `len(word)` in your dictionary if it doesn't exist and just retrieve the value in case it does. The second argument in `setdefault` is the default value you want it to store along with that key.

It's important to notice that in case the key already exist, the default value passed in `setdefault` **won't replace the old value**. This ensures that each list will be created only once and after then that same list will just be retrieved by `setdefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am not saying this is better in any way unless you consider compact code better. Your version (which is very ok imo) is much more readable and maintainable.

```
list_ = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]

# for python 2 filter returns() a list
result = filter(None,[[x for x in list_ if len(x) == i] for i in range(len(max(list_, key=lambda y: len(y)))+1)])

# for python 3 filter() returns an iterator
result = list(filter(None,[[x for x in list_ if len(x) == i] for i in range(len(max(list_, key=lambda y: len(y)))+1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
getLength = sorted(list(set([len(data) for data in sentence])))

result = []

for length in getLength:
    result.append([data for data in sentence if length == len(data)])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to do it in fewer lines, there is always comprehensions:

```
data = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "of", "seven", "words"]
# Get all unique length values
unique_length_vals = set([len(word) for word in data])
# Get lists of same-length words
res = [filter(lambda x: len(x) == lval, data) for lval in unique_length_vals]
```

It might be less clear, but useful if you just want to code something quickly.